# how to maintain the global state of the redux store while navigating through react components

Tags: reactjs, redux

The problem is with the "useNavigate" hook when login, I want to redirect to the Profil component without losing the global state of the redux store.

This is my App Component

```
import Profile from './components/Profile.jsx';
import Login from './components/Login.jsx';
import Register from './components/Register.jsx';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
<>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/login' element={ <Login />  } />
      <Route path='/register' element={ <Register />  } />
      <Route path='/profile' element={ <Profile />  } />
    </Routes>
</>
  );
}
export default App
```

And this is my Login Component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useLoginMutation } from "../services/api";

const Login = (props) => {
  
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const redirect = useNavigate();

  const [login, { isLoading }] = useLoginMutation();

  const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    const username = e.target.value;
    setUsername(username);
  };
  const onChangePassword = (e) => {
    const password = e.target.value;
    setPassword(password);
  };



  const loginHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();



      try {
        const response = await login({ username, password }).unwrap()
        if (response.data.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }
      redirect('/profile');

    } catch (err) {

      console.log(err);
    }

  };

  return (
    <div className="col-md-12">

      <div className="card card-container">
        <img
          src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png"
          alt="profile-img"
          className="profile-img-card"
        />

        <form className='flex flex-col justify-around' >
          
       
              <>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input value={username} name="username" placeholder='username' onChange={onChangeUsername} className='p-1' />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input value={password} name="password" placeholder='password' onChange={onChangePassword} className='mb-3 p-1' />
              
                <button className='bg-blue-400 p-2 border rounded-md text-white font-bold ' onClick={loginHandler}>Login</button>
               
              </>
        
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


export default Login
```

Here is a screenshot.
[image]

after submitting, the mutation is removed
[image]

I know that when redirect, the page is reloaded, but I don't know how to navigate without reloading

Comment: while I did not receive any answer, I think that the solution is to keep your global state in localStorage

Comment: in addition to that, the way we learned redux in the documentation is a little bit confused, you think that your whole application state should be in the store, but only small data should be there like user's authentication & shopping cart, but data like products and users could be huge and you could not store that in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

[ I am using React with Typescript ]
Using (for example) `import { useNavigate } from "react-router";` `const navigate = useNavigate();` and `navigate("/login/");` worked for me, while using `<Navigate>` tag didn't work well. I didn't use localStorage at all, but as I don't use that, the states were reseted by refreshing. Anyway, it looks tricky in some sense..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: so what is the use of your global state if you do not save it in localStorage ?    or what if you lose connection and refresh your page? your state will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

1. read about redux stores and the way to create and connect them to the components
2. initiate component state with values from connected store instead of empty strings

that's it.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my code, I was just looking for a way to maintain my state when redirecting or refreshing, I was not understanding the use cases of  redux well, and I used it in the whole project which is something wrong, for example, in an e-commerce website, a lot of people made their global state something like that: 
{products : [], customers : [], ......}, 
 what if we had 100000 products and 100000 customers, knowing that localStorage only has 5000 KBs.
so the idea is to keep only your temporary data in redux store, not the whole state

Comment: You can split your data for as many pieces in separate stores as you'd like. I was suggesting you get a hold of the store usage mechanics.